# Setup Dovecot in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install Dovecot on an Ubuntu server. For some reason, when I start the process, it informs me that the process is tunning, but when I search for it using  "ps -A | grep dovecot", I see nothing, which leads me to think that for some reason it stops. The mail log tells me nothing.
I have a sneaking suspicion that I configured something wrong in my configuration file, but I can't manage to find the problem.
The configuration file is located at: [dovecot.conf](http://www.loadingames.com/dovecot.conf)

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 2):

According to the Dovecot mailing list, in version 1.2 of Dovecot login_greeting_capability was removed and is no longer needed.

I'm assuming it is erroring out because you are running v1.2 or newer.

Here's two quotes I found regarding this configuration setting:

## 1.

```
details:   http://hg.dovecot.org/dovecot-1.2/rev/6d1214687c89
changeset: 7944:6d1214687c89
user:      Timo Sirainen 
date:      Sun Jun 22 07:12:27 2008 +0300
description:
Removed login_greeting_capability setting, it's no longer used.

diffstat:

1 file changed, 5 deletions(-)
dovecot-example.conf |    5 -----

diffs (15 lines):

diff -r 138a64b6dffe -r 6d1214687c89 dovecot-example.conf
--- a/dovecot-example.conf  Sat Jun 21 18:19:41 2008 +0300
+++ b/dovecot-example.conf  Sun Jun 22 07:12:27 2008 +0300
@@ -536,11 +536,6 @@ protocol imap {

list of plugins to load.
mail_plugins = 
mail_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/imap

 Send IMAP capabilities in greeting message. This makes it unnecessary for
 clients to request it with CAPABILITY command, so it saves one round-trip.
 Many clients however don't understand it and ask the CAPABILITY anyway.
 login_greeting_capability = no
 
 IMAP logout format string:
  %i - total number of bytes read from client
```

## 2.

> "Removed login_greeting_capability. The capabilities are now always sent (Lemonade requires this and it's not that much extra traffic)."

Answer (score 1):

```
wget http://www.loadingames.com/dovecot.conf
dovecot -F -c ./dovecot -n
```

tells me

```
Error: Error in configuration file ./dovecot.conf line 623: Unknown setting: login_greeting_capability
Fatal: Invalid configuration in ./dovecot.conf
```

So you'd want to fix login_greeting_capability